# Combine rows with matched and unmatched number with additional column association

Tags: r

```
X1 Y2 X3 Y4  
2  50 2  60
2  43 3  55 
4  80 5  34
5  30 5  59 
6  69 5  87
6  56 6  85
      8  22
      9  25
```

I have 4 column x as mass values (decimal) and y as intensity (decimal) as unequal column pair, I want to combine similar mass value (x) with highest intensity (y) and unmatched mass (x) as zero.

```
X1 Y2 X3 Y4  
2  50 2  60
3  00 3  55 
4  80 4  00
5  30 5  87 
6  69 6  85
8  00 8  22
9  00 9  25
```

How can I do the operation? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit messy, but makes the expected job.

```
   library(dplyr)
    
   a <- na.omit(table[,1:2]) %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarize(Y2=max(Y2)) 
   b <- na.omit(table[,3:4]) %>% group_by(X3) %>% summarize(Y4=max(Y4)) 
        
   out <- merge(a,b,by.x="X1",by.y="X3",all=T)
   out[is.na(out)] <- 0
   out
```

gives,

```
  X1 Y2 Y4
1  2 50 60
2  3  0 55
3  4 80  0
4  5 30 87
5  6 69 85
6  8  0 22
7  9  0 25
```

Data:

```
table <-structure(list(X1 = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, NA, NA), Y2 = c(50L, 
    43L, 80L, 30L, 69L, 56L, NA, NA), X3 = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 8L, 9L), Y4 = c(60L, 55L, 34L, 59L, 87L, 85L, 22L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L))
```